# Python tic tac toe program closes on "3 1" input

Tags: python

My problem: Python tab closes on "3 1" input.
This code is heavily inspired by [Hafeezul Kareem Shaik's tic-tac-toe game on geekflare](https://geekflare.com/tic-tac-toe-python-code/).
My code:

```
import random

class TicTacToe:

    def __init__(self):
        self.board = []
    
    def create_board(self):
        for r0w in range(3):
            row = []
            for c0l in range(3):
                row.append('-')
            self.board.append(row)
    
    def get_random_first_player(self):
        return random.randint(0,1)

    def fix_spot(self, row, col, player):
        self.board[row][col] = player
    
    def is_player_win(self, player):
        win = None

        n = len(self.board)

        #checking rows
        for r0w in range(n):
            win = True
            for c0l in range(n):
                if self.board[r0w][c0l] != player:
                    win = False
                    break
            if win:
                return win

        #checking columns
        for r0w in range(n):
            win = True
            for c0l in range(n):
                if self.board[c0l][r0w] != player:
                    win = False
                    break
            if win:
                return win

        #checking diagonals
        win = True
        for i in range (n):
            if self.board[i][i] != player:
                win = False
                break
        if win:
            return win
        
        win = True
        for i in range(n):
            if self.board[r0w][n - 1 - r0w] != player: 
                win = False
                break
        if win:
            return win
        return False 
        
        for row in self.board:
            for item in row:
                if item == '-':
                    return False
        return True

    def is_board_filled(self):
        for row in self.board:
            for item in row:
                if item == "-":
                    return False
        return True

    def swap_player_turn(self, player):
        return 'X' if player =='O' else 'O'
    
    def show_board(self):
        for row in self.board:
            for item in row:
                print(item, end=" ")
            print()

    def start(self):
        self.create_board()

        player = 'X' if self.get_random_first_player() == 1 else 'O'
        while True:
            print(f"Player {player} turn")

            self.show_board()

            # user input
            row, col = list(
                map(int, input("Enter row and column numbers to fix spot: ").split()))
            print()

            #fixing spot
            self.fix_spot(row - 1, col - 1, player)

            #has current player won
            if self.is_player_win(player):
                print(f"{player} Wins!")
                break

            #is game a draw
            if self.is_board_filled():
                print("Draw!")
                break

            #swapping turn
            player = self.swap_player_turn(player)

        #final board
        print()
        self.show_board()
        
tic_tac_toe = TicTacToe()
tic_tac_toe.start()
```

The Tic_Tac-Toe Game worked up until I typed "3 1". I tested multiple games and it would always close after that input.

I have tried editing the scope of the following, as I believe that is what is causing it to malfunction

```
  if win:
       return win
  return False
```

Unfortunately that has not fixed the problem. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: The logic in your *is_player_win()* function is clearly flawed. You should concentrate your debugging there

Comment: Upon further inspection, it seems "3 1" is an instant win. That may be related.

Answer (score 2):

This code is so badly written that I wouldn't take it as an example for anything.

But if you really want to know why it ends on `3 1` as input, you should look here:

```
    win = True
    for i in range(n):
        if self.board[r0w][n - 1 - r0w] != player: 
            win = False
            break
    if win:
        return win
    return False
```

Here `r0w` is not reset, it has the last value from the `for` loop, which is `2`, and it's not changing in the loop, so there's only one check made, which is `3 1`, translated to `2 0`, which is the current player, so that's an instant win.

I assume this was supposed to be a loop to check the other diagonal, but it's clearly flawed.